# Install and export INTERFACE only library, CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, installation

new CMake user here.

I've made a simple header only library, with the following CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(mylib VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#add_compile_options(-Wa -aslh)


# Define the library target
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE include/)


add_executable(mytest test/basic_checks.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest mylib)
```

From http://foonathan.net/blog/2016/03/03/cmake-install.html

I've learned there are several steps to getting a library installed and to have it useable from another CMake project. First it must be "installed" and then it must be "exported". Then there's find_package, but I'll cross that bridge after I've gotten over the first two steps.

So following the example, I figure that I could add the following to the bottom of my CMake file:

```
# Install the header file.
install(FILES include/mylib.hpp DESTINATION "include/mylib-${PROJECT_VERSION}")
```

But the guide talks about also using install on TARGETS, and then adding EXPORT to the target install commands.

How much of this applies to a header only library in which I have no other compiled code of files other than the header?

How do I apply the steps described in : http://foonathan.net/blog/2016/03/03/cmake-install.html
To an INTERFACE only library? The lack of .cpp files in my project is leading me to question which instructions apply and don't apply.

Comment: CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) says that *INTERFACE* library **may be installed**. Simply follow the guide.

Answer (score 36):

try this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(mylib VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
#add_compile_options(-Wa -aslh)


# Define the library target
add_library(mylib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(mylib INTERFACE 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION 0.1
    COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

install(TARGETS mylib
    EXPORT mylibTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Runtime
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Development
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include COMPONENT Development
    BUNDLE DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/mylibConfig.cmake.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib
)

install(EXPORT mylibTargets DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfigVersion.cmake"
              "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake"
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/mylib)
install(DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION include)


add_executable(mytest test/basic_checks.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest mylib)
```

the content of `cmake/mylibConfig.cmake.in` should only be this

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylibTargets.cmake")
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

if you do all of this, not only that it makes your header-only library 'installable', but it also makes it 'findable'. users will be able to import your library like so:

```
find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(MyApp mylib) # installed include/ path automatically added
```

Comment: @asynts woops. thanks for noticing this. It was a copy-paste error from my part. you don't need this variable at all if you know the file name. Most people prefer setting a variable name because if you want to change the name of your product later, you only need to change it at one spot. I'll fix this right away. Thanks!

Comment: It looks promising. Can you just add the content of "mylibTargets.cmake" to your answer please.

Comment: what's the point of `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylibTargets.cmake")`? I have tested and found that `mylibTargets.cmake` will still be generated even without `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylibTargets.cmake")`

Comment: @ 陳 力 this line is not for generating `mylibTargets.cmake`. It's for importing the installed product after. When you want to import the installed library into another cmake project, when you do `find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)` it will load the installed generated `mylibConfig.cmake` which will open `mylibTargets.cmake` which imports all of the installed targets into your project. If this line is missing, this won't work:

`target_link_libraries(MyApp mylib) # will fail here`

Comment: Use `COMPATIBILITY ARCH_INDEPENDENT` for header-only libraries instead of `COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#generating-a-package-version-file

Answer (score 4):

In my case the headers were contained in multiple sub directories and I simply wanted to map them to the install directory and preserve the relative file structure.  I gathered from reading [here](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/interface-library-not-getting-installed-and-no-error-reported/2185) that [file sets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#file-sets) are the preferred way to do this since cmake version 3.23.

This is the code I used to build the library...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.1)
include_guard(GLOBAL)
project(headerlib-proj VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES C)
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_library(mylib INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(mylib
        INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)

target_sources(mylib
        INTERFACE FILE_SET HEADERS
        BASE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        FILES myHeader.h)

install(TARGETS mylib
        EXPORT mylibTargets
        FILE_SET HEADERS DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib)

install(EXPORT mylibTargets
        FILE mylibConfig.cmake
        NAMESPACE MyNamespace::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/mylib)

install(FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibTargetsVersion.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/mylib)

export(EXPORT mylibTargets
        FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake
        NAMESPACE MyNamespace::)

configure_package_config_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibConfig.cmake
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/mylib)

write_basic_package_version_file(
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mylibTargetsVersion.cmake
        VERSION 1.0.0
        COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)
```

And the client...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(master-proj LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(myProgram)
target_link_libraries(myProgram PRIVATE MyNamespace::mylib)
target_sources(myProgram PRIVATE main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143782/2119944

Probably cmake/mylibConfig.cmake.in should look like this:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

include("${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/mylib/mylibTargets.cmake")
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

Otherwise it will point to local project dir.

Comment: I am sorry but your assumption is not exactly correct. If you have installed your lib config in /usr/local/lib/cmake/myLib/myLibConfig.cmake and your app is doing find_package(myLib), `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mylibTargets.cmake")` will resolve to `include("/usr/local/lib/cmake/myLib/mylibTargets.cmake")`  CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR will be giving you the path of where the code-generated mylibConfig.cmake is installed.

Comment: Also, I don't advise to use `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` here because any libs can be installed in multiple locations. you can list the lookup paths for `find_package` using the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` list and/or `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` list. Using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is too limiting imo.

Comment: Also, this is in the cmake documentation to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` for your code-generated config file https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html#config-cmake-in