# How to reuse an interface library in another project?

Tags: cmake

I want to reuse an interface library in another project. I tried it with:

```
find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(project mylib)
```

Which gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
```

Which I do not understand because I want to use an interface library why there is a linker error?

I made a minimal example of the [interface library and the consumer project](https://github.com/werto87/cmake_get_target). [Based on this stackoverlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143782/14468058)

Console output install library:

```
walde@localhost build]$ cmake .. ; cmake --build . ; sudo cmake --install .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/walde/projects/sandbox/cmake_get_target/myLib/build
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mylib/mylibTargets.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mylib/mylibConfigVersion.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/mylib/mylibConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/calc.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/calc.cxx
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/CMakeLists.txt
```

Console output consumer:

```
[walde@localhost build]$ cmake .. ; cmake --build .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/walde/projects/sandbox/cmake_get_target/use_my_lib_in_another_project/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target project
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable project
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:97: project] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
[walde@localhost build]$
```

Comment: Does the configuration provide a `mylib` target? Does `if (TARGET mylib) message("Found imported mylib target") endif()` print something? Btw: Installing a `CMakeLists.txt` file and some directories directly into the include install path doesn't seem to be a good option. Consider installing the headers to a directory named after the lib (e.g. destination `include/mylib` to install `calc.hxx` to `/usr/local/include/mylib/calc.hxx` in this specific configuration)

Comment: Your interface library is `myLib` (with upper-case `L`): https://github.com/werto87/cmake_get_target/blob/main/myLib/CMakeLists.txt#L6. But you refer it as `mylib`. This doesn't work, as target names in CMake are case-sensitive.

Comment: Note also, that Stack Overflow requires the code to be in the **question post**. *Links* to gihub project and to the answer in other question on Stack Overflow doesn't fulfil that requirement.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you. changing mylib into myLib helped to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to reuse an interface library in another project. I tried it with:
>
> ```
> find_package(mylib CONFIG REQUIRED)
> target_link_libraries(project mylib)
> ```

Three things:

1. **Absolutely never** use `target_link_libraries` without a visibility specifier.
2. When exporting targets, *always* include a namespace (via the `NAMESPACE` argument to `install(EXPORT)`) so that the `IMPORTED` target name contains a `::` sigil in it.
3. For consistency in the build and install trees, create an `ALIAS` target in the build with the same namespace prefix as your install will have.

The reason for (1) is that no-visibility is not the same as *any* of simply `PRIVATE`, `INTERFACE`, or `PUBLIC`, and it drops into a weird legacy compatibility mode when the styles are mixed. **Absolutely always** include the appropriate one of the three.

The reason for (2) is that names that contain `::` are *always* interpreted as CMake targets. That would make the error you observed absolutely impossible. CMake would instead tell you that `namespace::mylib` doesn't exist and you could correct the typo.

When `target_link_libraries` gets a name without a `::` sigil, it tries to find a target with the same name, but if that fails, then it forwards it on to the compiler driver with the `-l` flag (or equivalent).

For (3), consistency is nice and this will also help users of `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent` switch between that and `find_package` more easily.